# How to import excel into a html webpage

Tags: html, excel

My requirement is to load the excel sheet on to the html page. the excel sheet should get displayed when we give the page link. Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: Can the html display the excel data in any way or does it have to be specific?

Comment: I have all the buttons set at the top and bottom of my page.I need the data in excel to get displayed on the page as soon as it loads.